# Downloading a PDF file and saving it to temporary directory iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, nsurlconnection, nsfilemanager

My app displays PDF files from a list. I am struggling to understand the File Management in iOS. I read the guide here but it isn't helpful: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac//documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672

I don't get how to access the `/tmp` folder to write to it. I guess I'll need to use `NSURLConnection` with `URLsForDirectory:inDomains:` method. But I do not know what parameter the `URLsForDirectory:inDomains:` method takes to return the temporary directory and how to convert `NSData*` from `NSURLConnection`to PDF file.

Comment: The link you provided has same content as mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead you can save the file to `/Documents` folder and delete it later when it's not needed.

Have a look:

```
+(NSString *)writeDataToDocuments:(NSData *)data withFilename:(NSString *)filename{
    NSString *docsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
    NSString *filePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename]];
    [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    return filePath;
}
```

Comment: This is not the right answer. Temporary data should, under any circumstances, be saved in the documents directory.

Comment: Is it against the law or something? IMHO, it depends on the nature of the temp data. Since in the /tmp folder you cannot control the lifespan of the data, it might be better to use the docs folder and manage the temporary persistence yourself.

Comment: "Under any circumstances" may be a bit harsh. :) The problem with storing temporary data in the documents directly is that i may be backed up by iCloud (unless specified otherwise). Furthermore, the documents directory should, in a way, be handled by the user alone and not "abused" by the programmer. When the user decides to download a PDF, view it and then later (app sessions later) decides to delete it, that PDF should go in the Documents directory. But then it's no longer a "temporary" file.

Comment: Absolutely. It depends on your own personal definition of 'temporary'.

Answer (score 3):

1) Use **NSURLConnection** :

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"your url here"];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:fileURL completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                                      NSURLResponse *response,
                                                      NSError *error)
{
    if(!error)
    {
        NSString *filePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
        [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }

}] resume];
```

**OR**

2) Use **NSURLSession** :

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"url here"];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:fileURL completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                                      NSURLResponse *response,
                                                      NSError *error)
{
    if(!error)
    {
        NSString *filePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
        [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }

}] resume];
```

**Refer** : [nsurlsession-tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial) link.

Comment: This gives a warning: `Incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'NSString *(void)' to parameter of type 'NSSearchPathDirectory' (aka 'enum NSSearchPathDirectory')`

Comment: @ShantanuPaul : Check edited answer as i replaced warning code

Comment: Also raises exception.

Answer (score 1):

You get file path of file stored in `/tmp` using below code:

```
NSURL *tmpDirURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:NSTemporaryDirectory() isDirectory:YES];        // get /tmp folder path

NSURL *fileURL = [[tmpDirURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename"] URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"jpg"];

NSLog(@"fileURL: %@", [fileURL path]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *dataPdf = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:pdfOnline.url];

//Get path directory
NSArray *paths =
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,                              
NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

//Create PDF_Documents directory
documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory     
stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PDF_Documents"];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager]    
createDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectory, @"**PUT FILENAME YOU WANT**"];

[dataPdf writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```